# Is there an extension to add "Estimated Read Time" to the docs pages?

Tags: python-sphinx

We use Sphinx to write not only documentation for our product but also training material for our user base.

I have been looking for an extension which would automatically add an "estimated read time" metric to each html page generated in sphinx ...

something similar to what Microsoft has on their docs website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/introducing-docs-microsoft-com#estimated-reading-time

Our team could try to build an extension (maybe using this package: https://pypi.org/project/readtime/) but wanted to check with the community if something like this exists so we avoid doing redundant work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use readtime.js `https://www.npmjs.com/package/reading-time` for that

here is another option

```
https://codepen.io/balasubramanim/pen/xypRMP
```

try this